# Searching string in arraylist

Tags: c#, .net

```
class Program
{      
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string ss = "1,2,3";           
        string search = "2";
        ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
        a.Add(ss.Split(','));
        if (a.Contains(search))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("true");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("false");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Output is false . why is it ? I am serching same string in ArrayList..Please help

Comment: Stars say that question is *what color?*

Comment: While we appreciate you have provided code you haven't actually asked any question, which is kind of the point of SO. What is the problem and what have you done to try and fix it.

Answer (score 5):

You're adding an array of strings to your `ArrayList`. Return value of `String.Split()` is `string[]`, because `ArrayList` is untyped you can add any kind of objects (even of different types).

Change this:

```
a.Add(ss.Split(','));
```

To this:

```
a.AddRange(ss.Split(','));
```

As said ArrayList has not type for its items (it holds generic `object`s). It means you can do something like this:

```
a.Add(1);
a.Add("blue");
a.Add(AppDomain.CurrentDomain);
a.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Control());
a.Add(new string[] { "red", "blue" });
```

In this case a search like `a.Contains("red")` will return `false` because `a` contains a string array and search is performed against items, not against their content. For example:

```
string[] values = ss.Split(',');
a.Add(values);

bool x = a.Contains("2"); // false
bool y = a.Contains(values); // true
```

AddRange methods performs something like this:

```
foreach (string value in values)
    a.Add(value);
```

In this way `a` contains items from array, not the array itself.

**Little tip**
If you're learning C# I would avoid to compact code, be more prolix to see what you're doing:

```
string[] values = ss.Split(',');
a.AddRange(values);
```

It's more obvious what's inside your collection. Second step would be to use generic collection (strongly typed):

```
List<string> a = new List<string>();
a.AddRange(values); // OK
a.Add(values); // Compiler error
```

In this case compiler will emit an error if you try to add an object of the wrong type.

Comment: Thank you ADRIANO ...Can u plz explain why is it so ?

Comment: @user3007228 I added some more examples, I hope I've been clear enough!

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid ArrayList and other *obsolete classes*; use *generic 
collections* instead, e.g. `List<String>`: they are safer; in your case:

```
   List<String> a = new List<String>();

   // If you try erroneous "a.Add(ss.Split(','))" here
   // it'll be compile time error instead of misterious run time misbehaviour
   a.AddRange(ss.Split(','));

   if (a.Contains(search))
     Console.WriteLine("true");
   else
     Console.WriteLine("false");
```

By using *Linq* you can put your search in one line:

```
class Program {      
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    String ss = "1,2,3";
    String search = "2";

    Console.WriteLine(ss.Split(',').Contains(search) ? "true" : "false");
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the modified code for your reference.

```
class Program
{      
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string ss = "1,2,3";           
        string search = "2";
        string[] arr = ss.Split(',');

        foreach(string ar in arr)
            {
            if (ar.Equals(search))
                {
                Console.WriteLine("true");
                }
            else
                {
                Console.WriteLine("false");
                }
            }

    }
}
```